How to configure Nginx to redirect a path to another app on a different domain
I have two Vue applications running on different domains.
One is available on example.com, the second one is accessible on long-random-host-name.another-example.com.
What I want to do is making the second app available on example.com but on a different path, e.g. example.com/second/, and ensuring the long-random-host-name.another-example.com isn't visible on the browser.
How can I config nginx.conf to achieve such requirements?
